# Issue while posting data or pic to server

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I am facing issue while posting image in server. I am using httpConnection, and am getting issues such as Connection closed, Not Connected, TCP Timeout, Null Exception. Wwhile posting, I am posting a JSON Object,These issues occurs inconsistently, but happens randomly, I am not able to understand rootcause of issue?

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[20000];
            int bytesRead = responseData.read(buffer);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                byteArray.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = responseData.read(buffer);
            }
            byteArray.close();
```

ow i replaced to

```
        byte[] byteArray = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(request.openInputStream());
```

I am trying to understand whether these change will be useful?

I am posting sample piece of Code for posting pic

```
request = (HttpConnection) connect.getConnection();
            request.setRequestMethod("POST");
            request.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            os = request.openOutputStream();
            JSONObject jsonObjSMS;
            Vector dataValue = new Vector();//Vector for putting Images
            try {
                jsonObjSMS = new JSONObject();
                jsonObjSMS.put("strNo", MyObject.getNumber());
                byte[] encoded = Base64OutputStream.encode(dataValues, 0,dataValues.length,false, false);
                String baseEncodedStringArrayValue = new String(encoded, "UTF-8");
                dataValue.addElement(baseEncodedStringArrayValue);      
                jsonObjSMS.put("imageArray", dataValue);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception in JSON"+e);
            }
            os.write(jsonObjSMS.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));  
            os.flush();
            byte[] byteArray = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(request.openInputStream());
            jsonResponse = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");
```

Am I missing any piece of Code which is creating this error randomly?

Comment: It may happen due to different reasons such as connection timeout on server, size of file etc

Comment: check whether you are posting data using separate thread.

Comment: Identical question asked on BB forum, I suggest reviewing the responses there before answering here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Issue-while-posting-data-or-pic-to-server/td-p/2867062

Comment: Thanks for response for both there and here :)